# Flutter: Unable to find the lib folder

Tags: flutter, dart, lib

[image: I face this problem several time but i couldn't able to solve this, anyone please help me]

sometimes I can't run my project beacuse of couln't found my lib folder in project in android studio, How can I solve this?
I face this problem several time, but every time i create a new project because i couldn't able to solve this, anybody can help me please??

Answer (score 0):

you are opening the `android` folder inside your flutter project, Close the project and open it again, consider selecting the root project folder, not the `android` folder